# Revisions deos not work on the new update of wordpress 2018 ( WordPress 4.9.5.) .Went to Screen Options but does not appear

Tags: revisions

iaccidentally deleted some of my content then published it. Now my layout is all messed up . but cant find the revisions option on new update ( WordPress 4.9.5.)

Comment: Can you share more information? Have you check revisions in db? How did you publish content that it endup in deletion of revisions? This actions (publishing post) usually not ends as revision delete (only in case if you had a limited number of them).

Answer (score 0):

I think that revisions are disabled by default in the latest WP (but can't guarantee that).

I do know that if you want to enable revisions, then change an value in the wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3 );
```

That will save the last 3 revisions. Turn if off with a value of 0 or false. Save unlimited revisions with a value of -1.  See https://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions

Once revisions are enabled, you should be able to show revisions with the 'Screen' options on the post/page editor screen.